# passing location with handler from different class

Tags: java, android

I am new to the concept of Handlers, and i read quite a bit about handlers in android.Most examples though are with 2 threads both starting in the activity class, i want to pass the location from another class called Locac but it gives me NullPointer exception.

here is the Activity class

```
    Looper lupy;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


dbadapter mkola=new dbadapter(MainActivity.this);
mkola.openToWrite();






 Handler nok=new Handler(lupy) {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg)


    {

        Location locator=(Location)msg.obj;
        float lat=(float)(locator.getLatitude());

    }

};
```

here is the location class (notice i purposefully did not include any thread for the sake of simplicity)

```
public class  locac implements LocationListener  {

public Context Ctx;
Handler nok;
public static String okai="Ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE";


public static String moi="manag.GPS_PROVIDER";

public locac (Context context)


{
this.Ctx=context;

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     LocationManager manag;

     manag=(LocationManager)Ctx.getSystemService(okai);

     Message kol=new Message();
     kol.obj=loc;
     nok.sendMessage(kol);
}
```

and i get in the LogCat

```
 caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:226)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:134)
at com.example.alarma.MainActivity$1.<init>(MainActivity.java:39)
at com.example.alarma.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Comment: first of all you should not create a new Message, use nok.obtainMessage(...)

Comment: ok i replaced that with  int lati=(int)Loc.getLatitude();
    
  nok.obtainMessage(lati).sendToTarget(); i dont get the new point exception but i still am not able to see the lat in the Activity class

Comment: in handleMessage add Log.d(TAG, "msg: " + msg);

Comment: you are right  , i added the Log.d , but i dont see the message in the LogCat, also i see "the Value of the local variable nok is not used".I thought that the Handler is initialized automatically ? or should i put it in a constructor of the Activity Class ?

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues here, but the main issue is that your handler isn't initialized.  You need to pass it from your activity when you construct your `Object`:

```
public class  locac implements LocationListener  {

public static String okai="Ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE";
public static String moi="manag.GPS_PROVIDER";

public Context Ctx;
Handler nok;

public locac (Context context, Handler handler){
     this.Ctx=context;
     this.nok = handler;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     LocationManager manag;

     manag=(LocationManager)Ctx.getSystemService(okai);

     Message kol=new Message();
     kol.obj=loc;
     nok.sendMessage(kol);
}
```