# issues with Toast inside a Handler

Tags: android

i am strugling to get a handler display a Toast messgae , which also contains a variable extracted from the msg.obj.It doesnt give me any errors but the Toast message is not showing.Here is the code

```
 Handler nok=new Handler() {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg)


    {



Location locator=(Location)msg.obj;
float lat=(float)(locator.getLatitude());
Toast.makeText(m,"the latitude is+lat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

i also tried adding

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

{

public void run (){


Toast.makeText(m,"the latitude is" +lat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

but in this case the variable lat is not recognised outside the Handler, any ideas ?

the entire class is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String content="Asega kvo stava";
public static final Integer kom=2;
 Context m;
 Looper lupy;
 Handler ok;
Handler nok=new Handler() {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg)


    {
         System.out.println("Check"); 


         Location locator=(Location)msg.obj;
            float lat=(float)(locator.getLatitude());
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"the latitude is"+" "+lat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };
```

and the class posting the messsage:

```
public class  locac implements LocationListener  {

public Context Ctx;
Handler nok;
public static String okai="Ctx.LOCATION_SERVICE";
public static String moi="manag.GPS_PROVIDER";


   Location loc;

public locac (Context context,Handler handler)


{


   this.nok=handler;

    this.Ctx=context;

}



public void getLoc (Location Loc )

{
    if(loc!=null)

    {
        LocationManager manag;

         manag=(LocationManager)Ctx.getSystemService(okai);

         Message kol=new Message();
         kol.obj=loc;
         nok.sendMessage(kol);
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the variable `m`?

Comment: I dont see anything being called, its just all methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler nok=new Handler() {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg)


    {



Location locator=(Location)msg.obj;
float lat=(float)(locator.getLatitude());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the latitude is" + " " +lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Try using that.

Comment: put a `System.out.println("Check");` statement inside the `handleMessage` method to make sure it is actually being run.

Comment: ok , good point, for some reason it looks like HandleMessage is not being called at all

Comment: @user2557930 you should post your entire class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that that m is set to your Activity's context? Are you sure you are sending the message properly and handleMessage() is getting called?

Comment: yes i tried also with MainActivity.this , about how is the message called i have posted another question where you can see the calling class in the code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416264/passing-location-with-handler-from-different-class